# PHP SoapClient - Replace soap:address with different host

Tags: php, web-services, soap, replace, wsdl

I am using PHP SoapClient using the WSDL directly in Magento like this:

```
new SoapClient('https://localhost/api/soap/?wsdl');
```

I get the following URL as the soap:address:
https://myserver.myname.com/api/soap/index/?SID=123456abcdcefgh

Is it possible to get the soap:address value from SoapClient? There is no __getLocation method.

I need to replace the host in the soap address with localhost. But in order to replace it, I need to get the location from SoapClient somehow.

Can you give hints on how to handle this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Try this one: http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.setlocation.php

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you wan to do, but maybe good option for you is try to overwrite method `__doRequest`. It could looks like:

```
class MyServiceClient extend SoapClient
{
    public function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = 0) {
        $newLocation = 'https://myserver.myname.com/api/soap/index/?SID=123456abcdcefgh';
        return parent::__doRequest($request, $newLocation, $action, $version, $one_way);
    }
}
```

Look docs: [SoapClien::__doRequest](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.dorequest.php)

Comment: Thank you Piotr, The main problem is I can't read the soap:address value. There is no __getLocation method.

Comment: BUt where is this soap:address value? In WSDL?

Comment: Yes, soap:address is the endpoint of the web service which is defined inside WSDL (http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#_soap:address)

Comment: I think you must parse WSDL - for example by the DOMDocument - and find `soap:address` node value. This could be done in this extended class.